# Examples of algebras that have a bounded approximate identity

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

We note  that  $L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ is an algebra with respect to convolution without identity element.
However, regarded as a Banach algebra, $(L^{1}(\mathbb R), \ast) $ has a bounded approximate identity with respect to convolution, that is, there is a set $\{e_{r}\}_{r>0}\subset L^{1}$ such that $\|e_{r}\|_{L^{1}}\leq C$ for all $r>0$ and $C$ is some constant and $\|e_{r}\ast f- f\|_{L^{1}} \to 0$ as $r\to 0$ for $f\in L^{1}.$

**My Questions are:** (1) What are other examples of Banach algebras (preferably function spaces) that have a bounded approximate identity?
(2) Is $L^{1}$ the only convolution algebra which has a bounded approximate identity?

Comment: A non-function space: $A:= \mathcal{K}(\ell^2)$, the space of compact operators on $\ell^2$. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $P_n$ be the projection onto the first $n$ components, then $\{P_n\}$ forms an approximate identity for $A$.

Comment: Consider $\mathcal{A}=C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that vanish at $\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, of course if $G$ is any locally compact abelian group then $L^1(G)$ is a Banach algebra under convolution. If $G$ is not discrete then $L^1(G)$ has no identity, while if $G$ is first-countable then there is a bounded approximate identity. (If $G$ is not first countable there's still a *net* that gives a bounded approximate identity, but perhaps not a sequence.)

Say $K$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, $K$ is not compact, but $K$ is a countable union of compact sets. Let $A=C_0(K)$, the space of functions that vanish at infinity. Then $A$ is a Banach algebra (with pointwise multiplication) with no identity but with a bounded approximate identity. (Again, if you settle for a net instead of a sequence you don't need to assume that $K$ is a countable union of compact sets.)

Comment: DUC@Thnaks: Is it true that $C_{0}(\mathbb R) \ast C_{0}(\mathbb R) \subset C_{0}(\mathbb R)$? Kindly advice me; thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry. The multiplication in $C_0(K)$ is pointwise multiplication, not convolution.

Answer (score 3):

- Every (non-unital) C*-algebra has a bounded approximate identity
  consisting of self-adjoint elements.
- Every [amenable Banach algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_Banach_algebra) has a bounded approximate identity and this class of algebras is quite substantial.
- If $X$ is a Banach space with the bounded approximation property, then the algebra $\mathscr{K}(X)$ of compact operators on $X$ has a bounded left approximate identity.

See

> H.G. Dales, *Banach Algebras and Automatic Continuity*, Clarenton Press, 2001.

Comment: Would please add reference(paper or books etc..) in  your answer? (I find the answer very interesting... )

Comment: @Inquisitive, done.

Answer (score -1):

I am interested in the Sobolev algebra W^{1,2} of absolutely continuous functions *f* on the non negative half line such that both *f* and *f'* are square integrable. This is a Banach algebra without a unit under pointwise multiplication, and it does have an approximate identity.

However, there is no *bounded* approximate identity in W^{1,2}.

As a matter of fact, if *A* is a Banach algebra without a unit, that is reflexive regarded as a Banach space, and whose product is separately weakly continuous, then  every approximate identity in *A* is unbounded. The reason is that for a bounded approximate identity *(e_n)* there would be a weakly convergent subsequence, still an approximate identity, that would converge to a unit, a contradiction.